# Solve Linear Linear Regression with Linear Inequality Constraints for $ y = -a x + b $ Model

Tags: statistics, convex-optimization, regression, least-squares, linear-regression

Need to find some formula how to calculate `a` and `b` of some equation if `a` < 0

> y= - ax + b

What is the easiest way to draw a line when i have `a` < 0?

And my Dataset is something like that:

```
9 1
8 2
7 3
6 4
5 5
4 6
3 7
2 8
1 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is basically:

$$\begin{align*}
\arg \min_{ \theta } \quad & \frac{1}{2} \left\| M \theta - y \right\|_{2}^{2} \\
\text{subject to} \quad & {z}^{T} \theta \leq 0
\end{align*}$$

Where $ \theta \in \mathbb{R}^{2} $, namely $ {\theta}_{1} = a $, $ {\theta}_{1} = b $ and $ z = {\left[ 1, 0 \right]}^{T} $.

This is a simple Least Squares with Linear Inequality Constraints.
You'll be able to solve it using many methods (Even Projected Gradient Descent will do or any MATLAB Built In solver).

**Remark**
Pay attention that in order to make it convex optimization problem I set the constraint to be weak inequality.
The model will chose $ {\theta}_{1} = 0 $ only in case a constant value function (DC) performs better than Linear Function.